# How to avoid using a sub query for my query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables The first table GroceryStores looks like this

```
GsName | OrganizationId
-----------------------
'Olymp'| 1
'Carul'| 2
'Caref'| 3
'Viveo'| 2
'Suces'| 4
```

The second table Organizations looks like this

```
Id | Code | ParentOrganizationId
--------------------------------
1  | 'AB' | 0
2  | 'CD' | 3
3  | 'EF' | 4
4  | 'GH' | 0
```

Where GroceryStores.OrganizationId and Organizations.Id are the same.

The query is supposed to return all the GsName that match a given OrganizationId and its respective ParentOrganization.

I have tried this query but it only works when a GroceryStore belong to only one Organization but one GroceryStore can have a ParentOrganization and a GrandparentOrganization and different GroceryStores can belong to the same Organization. Also, one GroceryStore can belong to one Organization and that Organization might not have a ParentOrganization

```
SELECT GsName
FROM GroceryStores INNER JOIN Organizations
ON ParentOrganizationId = Id
WHERE OrganizationId = @Organization
OR WHERE OrganizationId = (SELECT ParentOrganizationId FROM Organizations 
WHERE Id = @Organization)
```

Comment: >My query fails when the subquery returns more than one GsName. 

based on the given data, it should not fail since there would only be a single parentorganizationId. can you show excepted output that you are looking for? my guess is you want to traverse the hierarchy and show all grocery stores

Comment: It was failing with the error 'subquery returned more than one value' when I had the subquery be ParentOrganizationId = @Organization but I fixed it in this question. But I am still not getting the result that I am looking for. So if I declare a variable Organization and give it the value of 2 the query should return 'Carul', 'Viveo', 'Caref', and 'Suces'

Comment: are you using SQL Server?

Comment: yes, I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you try, IN in place of EQUAL , when you say EQUAL you have to make sure SUBQUERY only returns 1 row , that you can do if you wish by using the LIMIT 1 in the query

```
    SELECT GsName
    FROM GroceryStores INNER JOIN Organizations
    ON ParentOrganizationId = Id
    WHERE OrganizationId = @Organization
    OR WHERE OrganizationId IN (SELECT ParentOrganizationId FROM Organizations 
    WHERE Id = @Organization)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to traverse the parent hierarchy, use [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) like this:

```
WITH Org
AS
(
    SELECT Id,ParentOrganizationId 
    FROM Organizations
    WHERE Id = @Org
    UNION ALL
    SELECT O.Id,O.ParentOrganizationId
    FROM Org O1
    INNER JOIN Oranizations O
    ON O1.ParentOrganizationId = O.Id
)
SELECT GsName 
FROM GroceryStores
WHERE OrganizationId IN
(
    SELECT Id FROM Org
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent your query to fail during execution change your query to this,
note that I've replaced `=` with `IN`.

```
SELECT GsName
FROM GroceryStores INNER JOIN Organizations
ON ParentOrganizationId = Id
WHERE OrganizationId = @Organization
OR WHERE OrganizationId IN (SELECT ParentOrganizationId FROM Organizations 
WHERE Id = @Organization)
```